# Hosted chat/across other sites/etc

Tags: discussion, chat

This might have been asked already, but any plans  to spread this tech out so we can use it elsewhere?

It would amazing to instantly add chat capability to a website without having to fuss about with IRC, etc etc.

Or is this a dumb question because it's already planned/already decided against :O

Answer (score 1):

Fussing with IRC isn't that bad these days. The web chat clients that 5by5 and TWiT use are pretty sweet and easy to embed.

They use the [freenode web chat](http://webchat.freenode.net/) interface. More techy users can always connect with their IRC clients if they wish.

Comment: I would also add that there's always Jabber as well.